# Add columns by name from the CSV file to the datagridview C#

Tags: c#, csv, import, datagridview

please tell me how to **add column data by name from a csv file?** At least I was looking for a link where to look, but I didn't find a working code.

I want to find **the "Start Date" column and add it to the datagridview** . Please help me fix the code.
**here is the view of the table (see picture)**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy7EY.png)

| Period Number | Start Date |
| --- | --- |
| First | 01.07.2021 |
| Second | 01.07.2021 |

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            if (lines.Length > 0)
            {
                //first line to create header
                string firstLine = lines[0];
                string[] headerLabels = firstLine.Split(',');
                foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
                {

                    if (headerWord== "Start Date")
                    {
                        dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerWord));
                        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
                        {
                            string[] dataWords = lines[i].Split(',');
                            DataRow dr = dtable.NewRow();
                            int columnIndex = DataGrid2.ColumnCount;

                             dr["Start Date"] =dataWords[columnIndex];
                         dtable.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }  
                }
            }

            DataGrid2.DataSource = dtable;
        }
```

Comment: And what is wrong with the code you show? Did you debug it?

Comment: It helps if you show us a few lines of your csv.

Comment: Period Number Start Date End Date Source
1 01.06.2021 01.07.2021 av_z_1_север_4кв
1 01.06.2021 01.07.2021 av_z_1_север_4кв

Comment: There are no commas in the shown line just whitespaces. The shown code expects commas as separator.

Comment: Also if i look correctly. You have 7 title columns but 8 value columns if i count the whitespace separators correctly. Or is something like Date End one column or two? Looks like you need to find out the format of your source csv correctly. csv is not that strict defined that just looking at the word csv tells anything. Please edit you questions with additional data and don't spread everything in comments and answers.

Comment: Below is the table view in txt and Excel (see the picture). But in fact, this does not even mean anything. Below I gave the code where I search for the desired column and output its data to the datagridview.

Comment: Excel has already interpreted the csv. It tells us nothing on how the csv really looks. csv is a simple plaintext format. Just look at it with an editor and take the first lines.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates all the `DataGrid2` columns for the `datatable` and then checks if there is a column called `Start Date`. If not, it adds the column and then moves each element of the `DataGrid2` rows to the `datatable`, and finally the datatable inside the `DataGrid2`.

```
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
if (lines.Length > 0)
{
    //first line to create header
    string firstLine = lines[0];
    string[] headerLabels = firstLine.Split(',');

    //all columns datadgrid2 push to datatable
    bool IsNotExistsColumnStartDate = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < DataGrid2.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        string headerColumn = DataGrid2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
        if (headerColumn == "Start Date")
           IsNotExistsColumnStartDate = false;
        dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(headerColumn));
    }

    //add column Start Date
    if (IsNotExistsColumnStartDate)
        dtable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Start Date"));

    foreach (string headerWord in headerLabels)
    {
        if (headerWord == "Start Date")
        {
             int j = 1;
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGrid2.Rows)
             {
                 string[] dataWords = lines[j].Split(',');
                 DataRow dr = dtable.NewRow();
                 for (int k = 0; k < row.Cells.Count; k++)
                 {
                    dr[k] = row.Cells[k].Value;
                 }
                 dr["Start Date"] = dataWords[j];
                 dtable.Rows.Add(dr);
                 j++;
             }
        }
    }
}

DataGrid2.DataSource = dtable;
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but the code does not add column rows, it only adds the column name.